# Problema al mostrar el calendario del fullcalendar

Tags: angular

tengo un problema al implementar el fullcalendar utilizando angular 4, el cual es que no me muestra las fechas, únicamente me muestran listado de números. Esto sucede únicamente con el calendario, los demas componentes o funciones, funcionan bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


// import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';
import { NgbModalModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { DemoUtilsModule } from './demo-utils/module';
// import { DemoUtilsModule } from '../demo-utils/module';
// import { DemoComponent } from './component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModalModule.forRoot(),
    CalendarModule.forRoot(),
    DemoUtilsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }


Component.ts
import {
  Component,
  ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ViewChild,
  TemplateRef
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  startOfDay,
  endOfDay,
  subDays,
  addDays,
  endOfMonth,
  isSameDay,
  isSameMonth,
  addHours
} from 'date-fns';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import {
  CalendarEvent,
  CalendarEventAction,
  CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent
} from 'angular-calendar';

const colors: any = {
  red: {
    primary: '#ad2121',
    secondary: '#FAE3E3'
  },
  blue: {
    primary: '#1e90ff',
    secondary: '#D1E8FF'
  },
  yellow: {
    primary: '#e3bc08',
    secondary: '#FDF1BA'
  }
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild('modalContent') modalContent: TemplateRef<any>;

  view = 'month';

  viewDate: Date = new Date();

  modalData: {
    action: string;
    event: CalendarEvent;
  };

  actions: CalendarEventAction[] = [
    {
      label: '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>',
      onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
        this.handleEvent('Edited', event);
      }
    },
    {
      label: '<i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>',
      onClick: ({ event }: { event: CalendarEvent }): void => {
        this.events = this.events.filter(iEvent => iEvent !== event);
        this.handleEvent('Deleted', event);
      }
    }
  ];

  refresh: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  events: CalendarEvent[] = [
    {
      start: subDays(startOfDay(new Date()), 1),
      end: addDays(new Date(), 1),
      title: 'A 3 day event',
      color: colors.red,
      actions: this.actions
    },
    {
      start: startOfDay(new Date()),
      title: 'An event with no end date',
      color: colors.yellow,
      actions: this.actions
    },
    {
      start: subDays(endOfMonth(new Date()), 3),
      end: addDays(endOfMonth(new Date()), 3),
      title: 'A long event that spans 2 months',
      color: colors.blue
    },
    {
      start: addHours(startOfDay(new Date()), 2),
      end: new Date(),
      title: 'A draggable and resizable event',
      color: colors.yellow,
      actions: this.actions,
      resizable: {
        beforeStart: true,
        afterEnd: true
      },
      draggable: true
    }
  ];

  activeDayIsOpen = true;

  constructor(private modal: NgbModal) {}

  dayClicked({ date, events }: { date: Date; events: CalendarEvent[] }): void {
    if (isSameMonth(date, this.viewDate)) {
      if (
        (isSameDay(this.viewDate, date) && this.activeDayIsOpen === true) ||
        events.length === 0
      ) {
        this.activeDayIsOpen = false;
      } else {
        this.activeDayIsOpen = true;
        this.viewDate = date;
      }
    }
  }

  eventTimesChanged({
    event,
    newStart,
    newEnd
  }: CalendarEventTimesChangedEvent): void {
    event.start = newStart;
    event.end = newEnd;
    this.handleEvent('Dropped or resized', event);
    this.refresh.next();
  }

  handleEvent(action: string, event: CalendarEvent): void {
    this.modalData = { event, action };
    this.modal.open(this.modalContent, { size: 'lg' });
  }

  addEvent(): void {
    this.events.push({
      title: 'New event',
      start: startOfDay(new Date()),
      end: endOfDay(new Date()),
      color: colors.red,
      draggable: true,
      resizable: {
        beforeStart: true,
        afterEnd: true
      }
    });
    this.refresh.next();
  }
}
```

**Component.html**

```
<h1>calendario</h1>
<div>
  <ng-template #modalContent let-close="close">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h5 class="modal-title">Event action occurred</h5>
      <button type="button" class="close" (click)="close()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div>
        Action:
        <pre>{{ modalData?.action }}</pre>
      </div>
      <div>
        Event:
        <pre>{{ modalData?.event | json }}</pre>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="close()">OK</button>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" mwlCalendarPreviousView [view]="view" [(viewDate)]="viewDate" (viewDateChange)="activeDayIsOpen = false">
          Previous
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary" mwlCalendarToday [(viewDate)]="viewDate">
          Today
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary" mwlCalendarNextView [view]="view" [(viewDate)]="viewDate" (viewDateChange)="activeDayIsOpen = false">
          Next
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):'en' }}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <div class="btn btn-primary" (click)="view = 'month'" [class.active]="view === 'month'">
          Month
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary" (click)="view = 'week'" [class.active]="view === 'week'">
          Week
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn-primary" (click)="view = 'day'" [class.active]="view === 'day'">
          Day
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div [ngSwitch]="view">
    <mwl-calendar-month-view *ngSwitchCase="'month'" [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events" [refresh]="refresh" [activeDayIsOpen]="activeDayIsOpen"
      (dayClicked)="dayClicked($event.day)" (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)" (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)">
    </mwl-calendar-month-view>
    <mwl-calendar-week-view *ngSwitchCase="'week'" [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events" [refresh]="refresh" (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
      (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)">
    </mwl-calendar-week-view>
    <mwl-calendar-day-view *ngSwitchCase="'day'" [viewDate]="viewDate" [events]="events" [refresh]="refresh" (eventClicked)="handleEvent('Clicked', $event.event)"
      (eventTimesChanged)="eventTimesChanged($event)">
    </mwl-calendar-day-view>
  </div>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <h3>
    Edit events
    <button class="btn btn-primary pull-right" (click)="addEvent()">
      Add new
    </button>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </h3>

  <table class="table table-bordered">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Primary color</th>
        <th>Secondary color</th>
        <th>Starts at</th>
        <th>Ends at</th>
        <th>Remove</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let event of events; let index = index">
        <td>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="event.title" (keyup)="refresh.next()">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="color" [(ngModel)]="event.color.primary" (change)="refresh.next()">
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="color" [(ngModel)]="event.color.secondary" (change)="refresh.next()">
        </td>
        <td>
          <mwl-demo-utils-date-time-picker [(ngModel)]="event.start" (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()" placeholder="Not set">
          </mwl-demo-utils-date-time-picker>
        </td>
        <td>
          <mwl-demo-utils-date-time-picker [(ngModel)]="event.end" (ngModelChange)="refresh.next()" placeholder="Not set">
          </mwl-demo-utils-date-time-picker>
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="events.splice(index, 1); refresh.next()">
            Delete
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>

</div>
```

Utilizo estos componentes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**calendar.header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'mwl-demo-utils-calendar-header',
  template: `
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <div
            class="btn btn-primary"
            mwlCalendarPreviousView
            [view]="view"
            [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
            (viewDateChange)="viewDateChange.next(viewDate)">
            Previous
          </div>
          <div
            class="btn btn-outline-secondary"
            mwlCalendarToday
            [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
            (viewDateChange)="viewDateChange.next(viewDate)">
            Today
          </div>
          <div
            class="btn btn-primary"
            mwlCalendarNextView
            [view]="view"
            [(viewDate)]="viewDate"
            (viewDateChange)="viewDateChange.next(viewDate)">
            Next
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>{{ viewDate | calendarDate:(view + 'ViewTitle'):locale }}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <div
            class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="viewChange.emit('month')"
            [class.active]="view === 'month'">
            Month
          </div>
          <div
            class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="viewChange.emit('week')"
            [class.active]="view === 'week'">
            Week
          </div>
          <div
            class="btn btn-primary"
            (click)="viewChange.emit('day')"
            [class.active]="view === 'day'">
            Day
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>

})
export class CalendarHeaderComponent {
  @Input() view: string;

  @Input() viewDate: Date;

  @Input() locale: string = 'en';

  @Output() viewChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

  @Output() viewDateChange: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter();
}
```

**colors.ts**

```
export const colors: any = {
  red: {
    primary: '#ad2121',
    secondary: '#FAE3E3'
  },
  blue: {
    primary: '#1e90ff',
    secondary: '#D1E8FF'
  },
  yellow: {
    primary: '#e3bc08',
    secondary: '#FDF1BA'
  }
};
```

**date-time-picker.component.ts**

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, forwardRef, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {
  getSeconds,
  getMinutes,
  getHours,
  getDate,
  getMonth,
  getYear,
  setSeconds,
  setMinutes,
  setHours,
  setDate,
  setMonth,
  setYear
} from 'date-fns';
import { NgbDateStruct, NgbTimeStruct } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

export const DATE_TIME_PICKER_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => DateTimePickerComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'mwl-demo-utils-date-time-picker',
  template: `
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input
            readonly
            class="form-control"
            [placeholder]="placeholder"
            name="date"
            [(ngModel)]="dateStruct"
            (ngModelChange)="updateDate()"
            ngbDatepicker
            #datePicker="ngbDatepicker">
            <div class="input-group-addon" (click)="datePicker.toggle()" >
              <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <ngb-timepicker
      [(ngModel)]="timeStruct"
      (ngModelChange)="updateTime()"
      [meridian]="true">
    </ngb-timepicker>
  `,
  styles: [
    `
    .form-group {
      width: 100%;
    }
  `
  ],
  providers: [DATE_TIME_PICKER_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DateTimePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() placeholder: string;

  date: Date;

  dateStruct: NgbDateStruct;

  timeStruct: NgbTimeStruct;

  datePicker: any;

  private onChangeCallback: (date: Date) => void = () => {};

  constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  writeValue(date: Date): void {
    this.date = date;
    this.dateStruct = {
      day: getDate(date),
      month: getMonth(date) + 1,
      year: getYear(date)
    };
    this.timeStruct = {
      second: getSeconds(date),
      minute: getMinutes(date),
      hour: getHours(date)
    };
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {}

  updateDate(): void {
    const newDate: Date = setYear(
      setMonth(
        setDate(this.date, this.dateStruct.day),
        this.dateStruct.month - 1
      ),
      this.dateStruct.year
    );
    this.onChangeCallback(newDate);
  }

  updateTime(): void {
    const newDate: Date = setHours(
      setMinutes(
        setSeconds(this.date, this.timeStruct.second),
        this.timeStruct.minute
      ),
      this.timeStruct.hour
    );
    this.onChangeCallback(newDate);
  }
}
```

**module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {
  NgbDatepickerModule,
  NgbTimepickerModule
} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { CalendarModule } from 'angular-calendar';
import { CalendarHeaderComponent } from './calendar-header.component';
import { DateTimePickerComponent } from './date-time-picker.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    NgbTimepickerModule.forRoot(),
    CalendarModule
  ],
  declarations: [CalendarHeaderComponent, DateTimePickerComponent],
  exports: [CalendarHeaderComponent, DateTimePickerComponent]
})
export class DemoUtilsModule {}
```

Comment: Muestra tu codigo para poder ayudarte, no somos adivinos. LOL

Comment: buena noche, disculpa lo pase por alto, gracias por decirmelo.

Comment: No muestres el codigo como imagen sino como texto ya que nosotros queremos copiar y testearlo y no queremos perder el tiempo transcribiendo lo que muestras en la imagen.

Comment: gracias por las observaciones